# Publishing Failed - Xamarin Google Play Store

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to publish my app finally on playStore but i get this error. What could that be please?

[image]

Comment: Pretty difficult to answer with no information other than a generic error message. Might want to consider editing your question with more info...

Comment: @DavidMakogon, that is the only thing showing on the screen. There isn't any error log or something to show me what is going on

Comment: Please give us more details. What you've done before the error, show us your code (relevant parts) or your data…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Xamarin tooling. You can track this here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51599

You may want to try manually uploading your .APK to the Google Play Developer Console instead. Perhaps the issue is purely in the Archive Manager feature and not inside your .apk. If you can add a reproduction project to the bug report above, I can help investigate this for you.